# ThingsBoard: Multiple Circle GeoFences on Map

Tags: thingsboard

Is it possible to configure Multiple Circular (or Polygon) GeoFences for PER device on Thingsboard Cloud?

I have a requirement where a single device have more than one Geofence and I need to generate alarms when device moves in/out of these geofences.

I managed to successfully display a single circular geofence on map for my device and I can successfully generate Alarm for a single geofence per device, however, I would like to know if its possible to configure multiple circular geofences per device?